# between two specific value angular validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I have this input

```
<input type="text" ng-model="total" />
```

I want to set a validation rule to limit the `total` be between two specific `min` and `max` value, how can I achieve this with angular? I don't want to use input of type `number`. user will enter only positive integer numbers so we can assume that entered value is integer.

Comment: What is the min and max value for example ?

Comment: 100 or 200, they are configs given by server.

Answer (score 1):

```
module.directive('range', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                var parsed = val.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (parseInt(parsed) > parseInt(attrs.rangeMax)) parsed = attrs.rangeMax;
                if (parseInt(parsed) < parseInt(attrs.rangeMin)) parsed = attrs.rangeMin
                if (val !== parsed) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(parsed);
                    ngModel.$render();
                }
                return parsed;
            });
        }
    };
});




 <input type="text" range range-min="1" range-max="100" ng-model="total"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this method:

```
angular.module('app').directive('betweenValue', betweenValueDirective);
  function betweenValueDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: linkFn
        };

        function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel)
                return;

            var maxValue = parseInt(attrs['maxValue']);
            var minValue = parseInt(attrs['minValue']);


            ngModel.$validators.betweenValue = function (modelValue, viewValue) {

                if (ngModel.$isEmpty(viewValue))
                    return true;

                if (modelValue >= minValue && modelValue <= maxValue)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```